# Jetpack compose onClickLabel for Button and IconButton

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, accessibility

Working on accessibility enhancements for my app.

From [Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/accessibility#add-click-labels), I can see that `Card` has both `onClick` and `onClickLabel` as part of the API.

And for composables without `onClick`, we can use `Modifier.clickable` or `Modifier.semantics`.

But what about `Button`, `IconButton`, `FloatingActionButton`, `TextButton` and `OutlinedButton`?
Composables which have `onClick` as part of API but no `onClickLabel`.

This works as expected. But is this the correct way to write this code?

```
IconButton(
    onClick = navigateUp,
    modifier = Modifier.clickable(
        onClickLabel = "Navigate up",
        onClick = {},
    )
) {
    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Rounded.ArrowBack,
        contentDescription = stringResource(
            id = R.string.top_app_bar_content_description_navigate_up,
        ),
    )
}
```

This seems too confusing as `IconButton` expects `onClick`. So I cannot go with completely `Modifier.clickable` or `Modifier.semantics`.
Similarly `Modifier.clickable` also expects `onClick`.

So, I have two `onClick` for a single composable component which could easily cause a lot of hard to debug bugs.

**Reason for the change,**
To read "Double tap to Navigate up" instead of the default "Double tap to activate".

P.S:
Compose version - 1.0.4

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `Modifier.clickable` in this scenario because:

- the IconButton already handles clicks via its `onClick` lambda
- the `Icon` has a `contentDescription` field for accessibility

So all you need is this

```
IconButton(
    onClick = navigateUp,
) {
    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Rounded.ArrowBack,
        contentDescription = stringResource(
            id = R.string.top_app_bar_content_description_navigate_up,
        ),
   )
}
```

Comment: This was the code I had. I am customizing it so that it doesn't read "Double tap to activate".

Comment: This solution is incorrect as per the OP's requirement

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be the prettiest solution but I ended up doing:

```
      IconButton(
        modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp).clearAndSetSemantics {
            this.onClick(label = closeLabelDescription, action = null)
            this.contentDescription = closeDescription
            this.role = Role.Button
        },
        onClick = onClickClose,
    ) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_close),
            tint = RiotWhite,
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }
```